# Remove Minimum number from a list without min() or pop()

Tags: python, computer-science

My problem is:

> Write a function `def remove_minimum(values)`
> that returns the list resulting from removing the minimum value from a given list without using the `min()` function nor the `pop()` function.
>
> Do not print the list.

I have a code that sorts and reverses the list but I cannot figure out how to remove the minimum without using the `pop()` or `min()` function.

```
def remove_minimum (values):
   values.sort()
   values.reverse()
   
   return values
```

There is a problem on here already that I used to help me get to my code that I have right now but they use `pop()`. I tried to search how to make the `pop()` function but am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

you can return an orderer list and slice it, removing the first value.

```
def remove_min(values):
    return sorted(values)[1:]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_minimum(values):
    values.remove(max(values, key=lambda x: -x))
    return values
```

:-D

Answer (score -1):

**Best pythonic way to do that without using pop() and min() functions:**

```
def remove_minimum(values):
    return sorted(values)[1:]
```

**Or this version, if you want the list unchanged and care about the order:**

```
def remove_minimum(values):
    values.remove(sorted(values)[:1][0])
    return values
```

Comment: Let's don't use builtin *input* as the variable name.

Comment: You are right !

Comment: The code is very much correct, and it is the best answer following the question and it's instructions.

Comment: Not sure it is the best answer. Sorting scales worse than finding the minimum by iterating though.

Comment: @DavidW I like to talk based on the context of the language, this is quite pythonic. iterating is also clearly very good and has the advantage of not using any built-in functions but looks more like c++-ish.